# Line-Height being ignored?

Tags: css

I can't seem to find anything that quite matches my issue, here.

```
    .nav.top .main .buttonsWrap .button {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 32px;
        height: 33px;
        padding: 0 27px 0 28px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

That's my CSS.  For some odd reason, the line-height isn't working.  No matter what I set it to, it's just not doing anything and Chrome debug has it disabled.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What tag is this being applied to? Is it a button or input?

Comment: The effect of line-height is only on inline elements. When line-height is applied to block, inline-block or any other type of element that is not inline, the effects are on the inline descendant elements only.

Comment: Please add your mark-up. HTML elements can have default styling.